# 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range' while generating NPCs

Tags: python

I am making a procedural generator for NPCs and am having trouble with getting them to have children.

My code for generating founders (those with arbitrary birth dates rather than driven by a pregnancy algorithm) works fine

```
#Make Founders
for x in range (NumberOfFounders):
    y = str(x)
    z = 'Person' + y
    ListOfPeople.extend([z])
    ListOfPeople[x] = Person(random.choice(ListOfNames), random.choice(ListOfNames), random.choice(ListOfNames), random.randint(1,10957), 'Null', 'Null', random.randint(0,1))
```

But when I tried to use similar code to make offspring I get "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" from

```
q = len(ListOfPeople) + 1
r = str(q)
s = 'Person' + r
ListOfPeople.extend([s])
ListOfPeople[q] = Person(random.choice(ListOfNames1), 'NameMother', 'NameFather', CurrentDate, 'Father', 'Mother', 1)
```

I will post more code if it is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to append z (or s) to ListOfPeople then replace it by Person()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `ListOfPeople` has length `k` after generating the founders, then `q` is assigned to `k + 1`.

The expression `ListOfPeople.extend([s])` (which should probably be replaced with `ListOfPeople.append(s)`) will cause `ListOfPeople` to have length `k + 1`.

A list with `k + 1` elements can only be indexed between 0 and `k`. You try indexing it with `q`, which equals `k + 1`, causing `IndexError` to be be raised.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

What would be the advantage of append over extend?

Comment: @BrendanSleanbeck It's a method that specifically exists for the common use-case of adding one element to the end of an array. Using it makes your intent clearer and is the preferred approach.

Comment: I chose to use extend after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend).

My understanding was that append was adding a list within the list (hence the square brackets), but extend just added on to the list.

Comment: No, `l.append(o)` will just add object `o` to the end of list `l`. A list will only be added within a list if `o` is a list itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a few `print`s to your code, it is pretty obvious.

Say `ListOfPeople` is `[Person_1, Person_2, Person_3]`

```
q = len(ListOfPeople) + 1
# q = 4
r = str(q)
# r = '4'
s = 'Person' + r
# s = 'Person4'
ListOfPeople.extend([s])
# ListOfPeople = [Person_1, Person_2, Person_3, 'Person4']
ListOfPeople[q] = Person(random.choice(ListOfNames1), 'NameMother', 'NameFather',
# Index error because ListOfPeople[q] does not exist
```

What are you trying to achieve, anyway? Append `'Person4'` temporarily then replace that last item with a real `Person` instance in the next statement?

It does not seem to make sense, but maybe this is because you simplified your code for the purpose of your question.

Anyway, if I understand correctly, you could do all that in just one line:

```
ListOfPeople.append(Person(random.choice(ListOfNames1), 'NameMother', 'NameFather',)
```

BTW, here's a few tips:

Formatting a string with a number. No need to "cast" as `str` explicitly. You may use `q` directly:

```
s = 'Person%s' % q
s = 'Person{}'.format(q)
```

Accessing last element of a list. No need to get the length or the list and compute the index of the last element. Use negative indexing:

```
ListOfPeople[-1] = whatever...
```

Appending to a `List`. No need to create a list and call extend. Just call `append`:

```
ListOfPeople.append(s)
```